# Sorting an array of Observables based on an Object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am returning an array of Observables from firestore, and want to order them by the index I created within the object in the database.

They are stored in the database like so:

[image]

They then display in the UI in the order based on the key ID (Alphabetically), however, I want them ordered in the UI based on the index. I do, however, need to keep the id as the initial key.

I have tried mapping the values and using sort() to to order by index shown in the ode below, but still returns in random order.

This is how I have used map to try and order by the key value of index.

```
this.bedrooms$ = this.property$.pipe(
     flatMap((property: any) => this._property.getAllBedrooms(property.bedrooms, this.propertyId))
   );


   this.sortedBedroom$ = this.bedrooms$.pipe(
     map((room: any) => {
      return room.sort((a: any, b: any) =>
          b.index - a.index
       );
     }
     )
   );
```

Comment: What is `b.test` ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun updated my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is maybe related to this line `b.test - a.index` instead of `b.index - a.index`.

I would suggest another solution for this, getting data sorted from the firestore using `AngularFirestore` from `@angular/fire` :

```
this.afs.collection<Bedroom>('bedrooms', ref => ref.orderBy('index'))
```

Comment: Bedrooms is a subcollection so it was my understanding it cannot be ordered? I may be mistaken though

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(JSON.stringify(room))` before the sort call and add it to the question ?